# "While standing" vs. "stood"

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses

Original: I didn't react to her pessimism ,and tolerated her pessimism.

I didn't react to and tolerated her pessimism

I didn't react to while I was tolerating her pessimism.

Would you tell me if they mean the same thing? If not, would you possibly elaborate your explanations?

I am willing to write the second and third sentences in such a way that they would mean the same meaning as the original does.

Comment: Since no one has said so explicitly yet, for @nima_persian's sake: no native speaker of English would say any of those sentences (not the first, not the second, and not the third). The problem is, as GarysStudent pointed out, that "*stood [her] pessimism*" is poorly formed, whatever tense you use.

Answer (score 0):

*Stand* is not commonly used with *pessimism.*

Say the situation is you are having a conversation.  The other party says something pessimistic.  You do not react to her statement.

*"I did not react to her pessimism."*

or

*"I did not react to her pessimistic statement."*

or

*"I stood by and did not react."*

Comment: If you can *stand criticism*, why can't you *stand pessimism*? Presumably the intended definition of *stand* is [this one:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand?show=0&t=1408886375) *2b :  to tolerate without flinching :  bear courageously <stands pain well>*. Why doesn't it work with pessimism? And if this is the intended definition, *put up with* would be much better than any of your suggested corrections.

Comment: If just have not seen it in this context.  I can't stand much pain, but I can stand criticism.

Comment: I agree that the OP's sentences don't sound right, but I don't think you've identified the correct reason.

Comment: I think that some phrases *"don't sound right"* because our brains have not been conditioned to accept them.  Exposure to colloquial usage lets us hear what we expect without raising any "red flags."  I will change *appropriate* to something else.

Comment: @PeterShor: You can "*stand criticism*" because "*criticism*" is transitive. You can't "*stand pessimism*" because "*pessimism*" is intransitive, and *can't be directed at you*.

Comment: I have just edited my sentences. the followng sentences are the ones which I am willing to say.

Comment: @Dan Bron But you can say 'I can't stand her pessimism'. Some verbs have very idiosyncratic sets of nouns / noun phrases that they will accept as direct objects. Their interrogative and negative, and more complex usages are often more accommodating (*/?I stand her constant nagging / 'How do you stand her constant nagging' / I can stand her constant nagging because ...)